# Uploading files in ASP.NET MVC using AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Below image depicts a screen in my sample application which has
file upload functionality.

[image]

Below are the steps I followed to upload and save files in Database.

1. In this screen once user clicks "Browse" button and selects the file(s) that need to uploaded, an AJAX request will be made to server(MVC application) for each file selected.
2. For each upload AJAX request, server will save the file data(byte array) in session array variable and sends JSON response(which has file name and file size) to Browser.
3. Browser will display JSON response.
4. Once user clicks the "Submit" button , the file information which is already there in session variable will be stored in Database.

Following above approach I could implement the desired upload functionality.

Question: I would like to know whether this approach is correct, am I making
any mistake?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the audience to bounce ideas off. Implement it and ask a concrete question, or ask a more specific design-time question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Upload using AJAX is not possible. Check this approaches: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/